# Given limsup, prove lim

Tags: analysis

Suppose $\limsup |x_n|^{1/n} < 1$. Prov $\lim x_n = 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

My attempt:

$a_n = \sup\{|x_k|^{1/n} : k \ge n\}$ then $\limsup |x_n|^{1/n} = \lim a_n =: L < 1$

For $\varepsilon  = (1-L)/2$, there exists $N$ in natural numbers such that $-\varepsilon < a_n - L < \varepsilon$ which is $(1+L)/2 < (1+1)/2 = 1$ using the $\varepsilon$.

For $n \ge N \sup\{|x_n|^{1/k} : k \ge n\} < (1+L)/2$

so $0 \le |x_n|^{1/n} \le (1+L)/2$

then $0 \le |x_n| \le ((1+L)/2)^n$ (This is less than one, and since constants less than $1$ to some power decreases, it converges to zero eventually.)

By squeeze lemma, $\lim |x_n| = 0$, so therefore $\lim x_n = 0$

Is this correct or am I missing something? Also, as a side question, is there a website where it gives proofs and explains them step by step? I feel like I need more groundwork in writing proofs.

Comment: Please look at my edits to the question. What you wrote was nowhere near proper MathJax usage.

Comment: Another way to prove this is via the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) and the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be such that  $\limsup x_n^{1/n}+\epsilon=r<1$ Then, by definition of $\limsup$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow x_n^{1/n}\le\limsup x_n^{1/n}+\epsilon=r<1,$ for otherwise $(x_n^{1/n})$ would contain a subsequence converging to a number greater than $\limsup x_n^{1/n}$.

This implies that $x_n\le r^n<1$ so that $x_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Not true? Let $x_n = (e^{-n} + 1/2) \cos (n)$. Then $\lim \sup x_n = 1/2$, but no such $N$ exists. Need to revise to $(\lim \sup x_n ) + \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is logically okay. If there is something to say, I would say you may want to somehow "refine" the way of presentation.

By assumption there is some $0 \leq l < 1$ such that $\sup_{n \geq N}|x_{n}|^{1/n} \to l$ as $N \to \infty$.
Then $\sup_{n \geq N}|x_{n}|^{1/n} - l \leq |\sup_{n \geq N}|x_{n}|^{1/n}-l| < \frac{1-l}{2}$ for large $N$,
so
$
|x_{n}|^{1/n} < \frac{1+l}{2}
$
for large $n$,
i.e.
$|x_{n}| < (\frac{1+l}{2})^{n} = r^{n} < 1$
for some $0 < r < 1$ and for large $n$.
So $x_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: There's not a lot of "White Room" in this solution.   I guess you were at a "Cross Roads."

Comment: @Dr.MV, You bet :).